# Allocating Two Dynamic Pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to understand pointers.  Essentially, I'm trying to allocate a pointer to another pointer so that I get a two dimensional dynamic array.  I can either us malloc to allocate *A or (assuming I already have an array) A[1], but I can't seem to create a dynamic two dimensional array by first using malloc on *A, then using another malloc on A[1] to expand that section of the array.  When I try to access A[1][5] on my double allocated array, the compiler refuses to let me create the program.  How would I go about creating such a two dimensional allocated array? Thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *A;
    A = (int *)malloc(sizeof(A) * 100);
    A[1] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(A[1]) * 100);
    A[1][5] = 10; //
    printf("%d", (int)sizeof(A[1]));
    free(A[1]);
    free(A);
}
```

Comment: If you want a two dimensional array, A should have type `int **A;`

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now.  Essentially, you would need a pointer to another pointer.  One pointer would essentially be for the rows, another for the columns.  It's just difficult to visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you want isn't really a two-dimensional array but rather an array of one-dimensional arrays... something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   const int NUM_ROWS         = 100;
   const int NUM_INTS_PER_ROW = 200;

   // allocate a dynamic buffer of pointers; each pointer will
   // point to a 1D array of integers
   int ** rows = (int **) malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(int *));

   // for each row, allocate the array of integers
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++) rows[i] = (int *) malloc(NUM_INTS_PER_ROW * sizeof(int));

   // Populate the array
   for (i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++)
   {
      int j;
      for (j=0; j<NUM_INTS_PER_ROW; j++) rows[i][j] = 666;
   }

   // do stuff here...

   // Finally, free the data
   for (i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++) free(rows[i]);
   free(rows);

   return 0;
}
```

If you want a real 2D array (e.g. something that is laid out in a single contiguous block of memory, similar to `int array[100][200]`, you're slightly out of luck, since C doesn't support dynamically-sized 2D arrays, but you can always fake it using a 1D array and a helper-function, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Returns a pointer to the item in the array at the given row and column
int * GetPointerToArrayItem(int * array, int numIntsPerRow, int row, int col)
{
   return array+(row*numIntsPerRow)+col;
}

int main()
{
   const int NUM_ROWS         = 100;
   const int NUM_INTS_PER_ROW = 200;

   int * array = (int *) malloc(NUM_ROWS * NUM_INTS_PER_ROW * sizeof(int));

   // Populate the array
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; i++)
   {
      int j;
      for (j=0; j<NUM_INTS_PER_ROW; j++) 
      {
         *GetPointerToArrayItem(array, NUM_INTS_PER_ROW, i, j) = 666;
      }
   }

   // do stuff here...

   // Finally, free the data
   free(array);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is possible to create real 2d arrays in C by using VLA pointers (not actual VLAs, just the variably modified types). E.g., `int (*arr2)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *arr2 * rows);`. You can access this just like any 2d array, i.e. `arr2[row][col]`, but this is a true 2d array (in the sense of contiguous memory), not a jagged array as in your first example above. VLAs were made optional in C11, but with C23 the variably modified types will be mandatory again.

Comment: @adabsurdum thanks, I was unaware of that.   Does the value of `cols` have to be known at compile-time?

Comment: No, `cols` and `rows` can be runtime variables. Here `arr2` is a pointer to a VLA (of `cols` `int` values), but there is no actual VLA; only the VLA type is used.